# How to link exit menu button from packages with tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, package

I am trying to make an exit button in menu link from a modules package:

main.py:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import Menu

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Python GUI") 

from lib.function_def import stop

menuBar = Menu(win) 
win.config(menu=menuBar)

fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command= stop(win))
menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

win.mainloop() # 5 Start GUI
```

function_def.py in lib folder (where i added a **init**.py):

```
def stop(var): # 7
    var.quit()
    var.destroy()
```

I get the errror:   TclError: invalid command name ".!menu.!menu"

Can someone help me to understand please?

Comment: Use `lambda`: `command=lambda: stop(win)`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks !